# What is the right way to annotate list that can be reversed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

What is the right way to annotate the argument to allow for a list that could be reversed?

```py
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]
flipped = reversed(mylist)


def foo(l: list[int]) -> None:
    # assuming `l` is list object which can utilize any of it's methods.
    l.append(123)
    return

foo(mylist)
foo(flipped). # error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "reversed[int]"; expected "list[int]"  [arg-type]
```

Should we include both types?  Is there a better way to annotate this?

```py
def foo(l: list[int] | reversed[int]) -> None:
   ...
```

Edit: I tried to keep `foo` generic, but it was pointed out how `l` gets used in the function matters to the question.  Keeping the problem relatively abstract, `l` needs to be able utilize all the typical `list` methods (`append`, `extend`, `remove`, `insert`, etc)

Comment: It looks like `foo()` *can* take a `list` as a parameter. What does `foo()` intend to do with the list? (eg. will it `append()` more values? or otherwise mutate the list? will it index in, or something else?)

Comment: From the looks of it, your function will accept any iterable (since that's what `reversed` returns).  Why not say that?  It would work with a tuple as well, right?

Comment: @quamrana Would it change the annotation?

Comment: @TimRoberts do you mean `def foo(l: reversed[int]):` ?

Comment: I'm saying that you need to find out what is common about `list` and `reversed` which `foo()` actually operates on. Does your code work at the moment, ignoring the annotations?

Comment: What I mean is `def foo( l: Iterable[int] ):`.

Comment: All `list`s are reversible, and `reversed` is not a function, it is a class. `reversed(a)` generally produces an instance of `reversed`, **not a `list`** (CPython has special handling of `list`s, where it produces a `list_reverseiterator` object, but that's an implementation detail not known to the type-checker), which is why you're getting the message `Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "reversed[int]"`. You need to provide more details to what `foo` does to `l` before a proper type annotation can be provided.

Comment: Ahh, I see now that @quamrana asking about what happens in the function makes a difference.  I'll update the question.

Comment: @TimRoberts `Iterable` doesn't seem to work if the function contains `l.append()`

Comment: Neither will a `reversed()` list. Maybe your original annotation should stand and you need to call your function like this: `foo(list(flipped))`.

Comment: @quamrana that's not a bad thought.  I suppose `mylist.reverse()` could potentially work too.

Comment: You still need to mention whether `foo` does an in-place operation on `l`, or whether it produces a new list instance & does some internal operation & leaves it for garbage collection. If it does an in-place operation, then `foo` can’t take a `reversed` object, and you’ll have to reverse it inside `foo`.

Comment: @dROOOze let's assume `foo` wouldn't care what order the list is in for this example.

Comment: It seems like the annotation is correct. Passing it an iterator with no "append" method clearly won't work.

Comment: @dROOOze your answer seems to be the most correct here.  I didn't realize reversed wasn't returning a list.  If you want to copy your comment into an answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the right way to annotate list that can be reversed? [...] l needs to be able utilize all the typical list methods (append, extend, remove, insert, etc)

A regular list annotation will do just fine at signifying an object with all of the capabilities of a list. That includes being reversible. But, you've got to pass in a list for that to work. The call to `reversed` might not return a `list`, depending on what python you're running.

```py
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
flipped = list(reversed(mylist))  # type remains a list

def foo(l: list[int]) -> None:
    l.append(123)
    l[:] = list(reversed(l))

foo(mylist)  # fine
foo(flipped)  # also fine
```

On another note. Built-in behaviors usually have ***dunder** methods* associated with them. Being reversible, for instance, has `__reversed__`. If you need to specify a type-hint for an object that implements particular behaviors / methods, you can do that with the `Protocol` class.

```py
from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable, Any

@runtime_checkable
class Reversible(Protocol):
    def __reversed__(self) -> list[Any]:
        ...

def foo(l: Reversible) -> None:
    l.append(123)

    assert isinstance(l, Reversible)  # will it work?
    l[:] = list(reversed(l))

foo(mylist)  # all good
```

Comment: [`collections.abc.Reversible`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Reversible) already exists, so you could just use that.